# Send value in body from angular2 service

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular2-services

I have an Angular2 service

```
logIn (username, password): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.getUserUrl + username + '/' + password)
     .map(this.extractData)
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

which sends a request to

```
router.get('/authenticate/:username/:password', function(req, res, next) {
schema.User.find({ username: req.param("username"), password: req.param("password")}).exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err)
      return console.error(err);
      console.log("Load success: ", users);
      res.send(users);
    });
});
```

but i need a way to send the `username`, and especially the `password` in a way which doesn't expose it to the request itself

Comment: Then you should use post instead of get.

Comment: In the service, endpoint or both?

Comment: Both of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your methods to post

```
logIn (username, password): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.post(this.getUserUrl + "test", {username: username, password: password})
     .map(this.extractData)
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

node:

```
router.post('/authenticate/test', function(req, res, next) {
 var username = req.body.username;
 var password = req.body.password;
 schema.User.find({ username: username, password: password }).exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err)
      return console.error(err);
      console.log("Load success: ", users);
      res.send(users);
   });
});
```

Comment: Property 'post' does not exist on type '(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) => Observable<Response>'.

Comment: @Fripo I've forgot to change the gets to post. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)
It's no longer in the request, however i can still see it from the preview in the networks tab, but i guess that i log it somewhere?

Comment: @Fripo if you send it as a response (which you do I think with `res.send(users)`) you will see it in preview. So instead, you can send something like `res.send("SUCCESS")`. But even if so you will still see it in the headers of the network tab.

Comment: Ah, i can see that. Is there any way i can exclude it? I actually just need some feedback from the response, so i can log users in

Comment: @Fripo exclude what?

Comment: In the response it sends me the username and the password from the database. I guess that's bad to send the credentials back to the user and expose them like that?

Comment: @Fripo why? :-) the user already knows what password is typed. And as I've said if you still don't want it just send `res.send("SUCCESS")`.

Comment: Great thanks :) I'm not that much into security, i just thought that they could be picked up by someone